# Request user input during python script

Tags: flask

So basically I run a python script when a button is clicked on the web app. During this script, there is a possibility that I will need additional information. This does not always happen. So my question is, what is the best way to get additional information from the user after the script is running? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax on the client side to call the function to check if additional information is loaded and then actually run the script upon completion.